# Mapping a sequence of keystrokes to command-line commands

Tags: vim

Is there a way to map a sequence of keystrokes to a command-line commmand (a command entered after `:` in the Ex mode) in vim?

Comment: Sure! Can you give an example of what are you trying to do, or are you just asking in general ?

Comment: Just in general, lot's of times I find that I'm doing the same thing repeatedly but on the other hand, I don't want to create a key binding for it (I don't want another Emacs where I'm using modifier keys for all my commands)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, and it's intuitively called :map

Example:

```
:map foo :echo "bar"<CR>
```

No when in insert mode you press the keys `foo` vim will respond with "bar".
Type `:help :map`  in vim for more information.
You can place mappings you want to load by default in your .vimrc file.

You can independently map keystrokes for different modes, such as insert mode (:imap) and visual mode (:vmap). See also vim help on the subject of remapping (:noremap)

**Update**

If you want to use an alias for command mode (but this can be done for insert mode too), you'll want to use *abbreviations*.

To define an abbreviation for command mode, use :ca (which is a shorthand for :cabbrev). See vim help `:help :ca` and for more info `:help :abbreviations`.

Notice that unlike map, abbreviations are not replaced by vim commands but by literal characters. Abbreviations are triggered when you press space or enter.

Examples:

```
" let me type :syn=cpp instead of :set syntax=cpp
"
:ca syn set syntax

" fix my favorite spelling error
"
:abbr teh the

" this does something different than the :map example above
"
:iabb foo :echo "bar"<CR>

" this is ugly, misusing an abbreviation as :map by simulating ESCAPE press
"
:iabb hello <ESC>:echo "world"<CR>
```

Comment: This makes certain stuff more annoying though - if for instance I want to enter fo, then I have to way a while for that command sequence to execute since fo is a substring of foo. Is there a way to map command-line commands (commands entered after the : prompt) to a sequence of key presses?